# Why doesn't omitting "case" in switch...case throw error or warning in XCode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

While inspecting a non-functioning bit of code, I realized that I'd left the "case" out of my switch statements. The buggy code had the following format

```
switch (foo) {
   firstElem:
       ...
       break;
   secondElem:
       ...
       break;
}
```

Where `firstElem` and `secondElem` are part of an enumerated list. When I step through the code, it jumps from `switch` to the closing bracket, since it finds no match.

This was simple to fix, but it left me uneasy because **XCode did not complain at all** either at compile or run-time. **Why?**

1. Is there something in the structure of the language that makes a `switch case` harder to interpret?
2. Is there ever an instance in which you would *want* to omit the `case` statement to produce some other behavior (which I know nothing about)?
3. Does this happen in other languages? I know Objective-C is a "strict superset of C," so I assume the same might happen in C (depending on the compiler). What about Java? C++?

**UPDATE:** I'm using XCode 4.4.1 (although I'll go and upgrade in a sec). This is part of an established project.**

**FURTHER UPDATE AND REFERENCE** Kevin Ballard correctly pointed out that I was accidentally defining labels. For more info on labels and GOTO, you can find a discussion in *The C Programming Language* 3.8 in which Kernighan and Richie conclude that (although they might have some use in error checking)

> ... code that relies on goto statements is    generally harder to understand and to maintain than code without gotos. Although we are not dogmatic about the matter, it does seem that goto statements should be used rarely, if at all.

Comment: I just tried to remove the 'case' from a working app of mine and Xcode immediately threw an alert saying case was missing and offered to fix it.  I am on Xcode 4.3.3.  Maybe there is a code error high up and it is stopping Xcode from analyzing the switch case code?

Comment: and one of the things I love about Xcode, every now and then it just stops catching error and I have to quit and relaunch Xcode.

Comment: When I compile there are no errors or warnings. I tried restarting XCode, and had same behavior (no complaining).

Comment: C syntax allows a lot of things that don't make sense.  Some compilers will warn you if you do some of them, but they can't "legally" prevent you from doing something stupid and still be "compliant".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you have is a bunch of regular old labels inside your `switch`. That's perfectly legal. Xcode isn't complaining because a switch with no `case` statements is legal, although a bit strange.

That said, `clang` will emit a warning upon seeing a `switch` statement with no `case` statements. Are you using GCC?

Comment: Yes. My compile settings use "LLVM GCC 4.2"

But WHY would a switch without case statements be legal?

Comment: @BPMJ: Because a switch is basically just a fancy syntax for a bunch of labels and some logic to jump to the correct label. You can intermix other code all you want.

Comment: @BPMJ: If you want to hurt your head a bit, go look at [Duff's Device](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff's_device) (note: never use this today, it's obsolete). That actually uses a `do-while` loop that spans multiple case statements in the switch.